# Python integer infinity for slicing

Tags: python, integer, infinity

I have defined a slicing parameter in a config file:

```
max_items = 10
```

My class slices a list according to this parameter:

```
items=l[:config.max_itmes]
```

When `max_items = 0`, I want all items to be taken from `l`. The quick and dirty way is:

```
config.max_items=config.max_items if config.max_items>0 else 1e7
```

Assuming that there will be less then `1e7` items. However, I don't fancy using magic numbers. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing it, like an infinity integer constant?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no "infinity integer constant" in Python, but using `None` in a slice will cause it to use the default for the given position, which are the beginning, the end, and each item in sequence, for each of the three parts of a slice.

```
>>> 'abc'[:None]
'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `sys.maxint`?

Comment: This is only the maximum for native ints, not for longs. It's gone in Python 3, and collections may be able to grow larger than that (although most if not all won't, of course).

Comment: `sys.maxint` no longer exists in Python 3.5

Comment: @agcala yes that's what user395760 said :)